# Lubuntu - I can't play videos from YouTube using Firefox but in Chromium I can

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, chromium, youtube

I just switched OS from Windows 10 to Lubuntu 16.04 so I'm fairly a new user but not that hard to teach. Anyways, my problem is simply in the title... I know Google is my friend but I don't know what keyword to search anymore to fix my problem.

If there's more information you need to help me, don't hesitate to ask since I'm fairly new here and I don't know what information to provide.

**Edit:** And for some reason I'm having a hard time posting using Firefox as it was very slow but in Chromium its so fluent. I don't want to completely just switch from Firefox to Chromium as I feel more comfortable with Firefox. Maybe there's some way to fix this...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Youtube's html5 video player if you aren't already, as it is now recommended over flash.

Navigate to https://www.youtube.com/html5 :
[image: youtube]

Select **Request the HTML5 Player** if it is not already selected.
Type `about:config` in the URL bar.

Set all `media.*` values to default.

Comment: Thank you! Everything was alright in the https://www.youtube.com/html5 part except on that `about:config`. I wonder why is it like that. Do you know the reason why it wasn't set to default or is there any reason behind it not being default?

Comment: They should all be default in a new installation, as that is.... well *default*. You could have an add-on installed that changed some options. Did you import a profile to firefox?

Comment: Nope, didn't touch anything... I followed this guide though about things to do first in Lubuntu https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/first-lubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I've just disabled all addonds and plugins about flash installed with my firefox browser. Then, it worked. My OS es lubuntu:

$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS \n \l

Regards,
MR